# I'am confused with this react Error message?

Tags: reactjs

React error message wont construct my code

I'am confused on the pathway and terminal .....

Ive already tried changing the name of my app and that doesn't work

https://gist.github.com/patrowheels/fece9597d6862094a1a3672b9d6cdecf

Comment: try `../components`

Answer (score 1):

You are importing as:

```
import Header from "./components/Header"
import MainContent from "./components/MainContent"
import Footer from "./components/Footer"
```

Yet, you say your file names are `header.js`, `footer.js`, etc.

Try importing as:

```
import Header from "./components/header.js"
import MainContent from "./components/maincontent.js"
import Footer from "./components/footer.js"
```

so the filenames match.